# What does SAFE[] means here?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char

So I look at UrlEncode function from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/string/conversions/article.php/c12759):

```
std::string UriEncode(const std::string & sSrc)
{
   const char DEC2HEX[16 + 1] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
   const unsigned char * pSrc = (const unsigned char *)sSrc.c_str();
   const int SRC_LEN = sSrc.length();
   unsigned char * const pStart = new unsigned char[SRC_LEN * 3];
   unsigned char * pEnd = pStart;
   const unsigned char * const SRC_END = pSrc + SRC_LEN;

   for (; pSrc < SRC_END; ++pSrc)
   {
      if (SAFE[*pSrc]) 
         *pEnd++ = *pSrc;
      else
      {
         // escape this char
         *pEnd++ = '%';
         *pEnd++ = DEC2HEX[*pSrc >> 4];
         *pEnd++ = DEC2HEX[*pSrc & 0x0F];
      }
   }

   std::string sResult((char *)pStart, (char *)pEnd);
   delete [] pStart;
   return sResult;
}
```

It does not compile under my Visual Studio 2008. How to make it work (beter not using any special windows functions), what does `SAFE[ const unsigned char ]` means anyway?

***Update:***
Looking at zip file under source I found

```
const char SAFE[256] =
{
    /*      0 1 2 3  4 5 6 7  8 9 A B  C D E F */
    /* 0 */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* 1 */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* 2 */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* 3 */ 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,

    /* 4 */ 0,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,
    /* 5 */ 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* 6 */ 0,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,
    /* 7 */ 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,0, 0,0,0,0,

    /* 8 */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* 9 */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* A */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* B */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,

    /* C */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* D */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* E */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
    /* F */ 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0
};
```

It scares me... How to make it usable in C++ class?

Comment: @John - Actually, on SO, he is encouraged to instead post his own answer below in the answers section.  But I think he is actually asking what the *definition* of SAFE means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SAFE` simply appears to be an array marking which characters are valid in a URI. It even has row and column comments to make it easier to see which entry's which.

You'll see that the first valid character is 0x30, or `0`. 0x41-0x5A are the capital letters, etc.

This way, `SAFE[*pSrc]` is simply non-zero ("true") when a character is valid in a URI, and zero ("false") when not.

Answer (score 3):

#### Meaning

I'd say `SAFE` contains flags for safe and unsafe characters.

So if `SAFE[c]` evaluates to `true` (i.e. the array value is not `0`) the character is safe and does not need to be encoded.

#### "How to make it usable in C++"

Comparing the array with [the character handling functions in `cctype.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/) I think you can simply replace the array with a call to `isalnum()`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try searching through the source for SAFE? It's a 256-wide array defined on line 72. Basically, all ASCII characters in the range 0-9, a-z and A-Z are marked *safe*, while the other are not safe.

So, the for loop is running through the string, and if the current character isn't in the range list as safe it is converted to it's hex value.